# Kill A pid only if it is specific Program/Process

Tags: linux, bash

Assuming that we have a PID Number how do i write `ONE bash command` to kill it if it is is specific program?

For example let's that that we have a pid number **20000** . *I want to kill that PID only if it is an FFmpeg Process*

Comment: It's unlikely that pid 20000 will be ffmpeg. [What are you _really_ trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in ONE bash command.

You can use the [ps](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) command to return the name of the process with a specified PID. in particular the `-p <pid>` switch is useful as is `-o` which allows you to specify a list of process parameters e.g. ppid, pmem etc. Of particular use here is `-o comm` which instructs ps  to return the `command`. It is easy to combine the `-p <pid>` and `-o comm` to return just the command for the specified `<pid>`. you'll probably find the `--no-header` switch useful here too.

Ok so now you've got ps to return the command name of the process with PID `<pid>` all you need to do is compare it to `FFmpeg` and issue a kill command.

That's all fairly simple stuff so I'll leave it as an exercise for your education now that you have a few pointers.

Comment: `[ $(readlink /proc/$PID/exe) == "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" ] && kill $PID`

Comment: Awww you've gone and spoiled the OP's fun now ;)

Comment: That's my job. Spoiling users' fun. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write process name directly with killall command.

**killall ffmpeg**

Answer (score -1):

```
ps -f -p 20000 | grep ffmpeg > /dev/null && echo kill 20000
```

Remove the `echo` in the final version

- ps -f -p 20000

  Show process data from PID 20000
- grep ffmpeg > /dev/null

  Find if string from `ps` contains the string `ffmpeg`. If the string is not found a return code unequal 0 is returned. `> /dev/null` ignore printed output.
- && echo kill 20000

  `&&` Only do following command if return code from previous command was 0. So do the kill `20000` only if the substring `ffmpeg` was found in grep